# How to delete a Siri Shortcut

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I am trying to remove all support for Siri Shortcuts from my app. I have two types of shortcuts, both are made by donating `INInteraction`'s.

```
func createDocIntent(for template: Document) -> CreateDocumentIntent {
    let intent = CreateDocumentIntent()
    intent.templateURI = template.URI.absoluteString
    intent.templateTitle = template.title.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = String(format: LS("siri-shortcut.create-document-suggested-phrase"), template.title.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
    return intent
}

func donateCreateDocShortcut(for template: Document) {
    let intent = self.createDocIntent(for: template)
    INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil).donate { error in
        if let error = error {
            dprintln("Failed to donate CreateDocument shortcut to Siri with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

To remove the shortcuts I have tried removing the Intent subclasses created in my Info.plist, and I have tried calling both `INInteraction.deleteAll` and `NSUserActivity.deleteAllSavedUserActivities`, but neither seem to actually delete the shortcuts (see below). Any shortcuts the user has made are still available in the Shorcuts.app, and can still be triggered by using voice commands.

```
    INInteraction.deleteAll { (error) in
        guard let error = error else { return }
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    NSUserActivity.deleteAllSavedUserActivities {
        // Nothing to do
    }
```

Is there something else I should be doing to remove existing Siri Shortcuts?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution ? I have the same problem not being able to delete a Siri Shortcut anymore....

Comment: @iKK It's been confirmed by Apple that this is intended behavior.